# Last time value changed from negative to positive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can you return the date by PersonID when the last time the Balance field went from a negative value to a positive value?

In the sample data below, for PersonID 1 it happened for 8th July 2019, for PersonID 2 it happened for 8th August 2019. There can be multiple times the value changes from negative to positive but it should only reference the latest time it happens.

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

I have the below sample data

```
Create Table #temp
(
    PersonID int,
    ActionDate date,
    Balance money
)
insert into #temp
(
    PersonID,
    ActionDate,
    Balance
)
select
    1,
    '01 Jul 2019',
    -100
union all
select
    1,
    '02 Jul 2019',
    -45
union all
select
    1,
    '03 Jul 2019',
    -80
union all
select
    1,
    '04 Jul 2019',
    -20
union all
select
    1,
    '05 Jul 2019',
    40
union all
select
    1,
    '06 Jul 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    1,
    '07 Jul 2019',
    -90
union all
select
    1,
    '08 Jul 2019',
    -150
union all
select
    1,
    '09 Jul 2019',
    100
union all
select
    1,
    '10 Jul 2019',
    120
union all
select
    1,
    '11 Jul 2019',
    130
union all
select
    1,
    '12 Jul 2019',
    140
--
union all
select
    2,
    '01 Aug 2019',
    -100
union all
select
    2,
    '02 Aug 2019',
    -45
union all
select
    2,
    '03 Aug 2019',
    80
union all
select
    2,
    '04 Aug 2019',
    20
union all
select
    2,
    '05 Aug 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    2,
    '06 Aug 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    2,
    '07 Aug 2019',
    40
union all
select
    2,
    '08 Aug 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    2,
    '09 Aug 2019',
    45
union all
select
    2,
    '10 Aug 2019',
    65
union all
select
    2,
    '11 Aug 2019',
    23
union all
select
    2,
    '12 Aug 2019',
    105
```

Comment: I notice that on rows 17 ~ 20 there's multiple changes on the same date; you may want to consider changing the column to datetime to ensure a consistent order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want using `not exists`.  It finds the last negative balance:

```
select t.*
from #temp t
where t.balance < 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from #temp t2
                  where t2.personid = t.personid and
                        t2.actiondate > t.actiondate and
                        t2.balance < 0
                 );
```

If you want the last change, you can filter using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by actiondate desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(balance) over (partition by personid order by actiondate) as next_balance
            from #temp t
           ) t
      where t.balance < 0 and
            t.next_balance > 0
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```