# Last time value changed from negative to positive, return current row and next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a follow-up question from [Last time value changed from negative to positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582657/last-time-value-changed-from-negative-to-positive), where I was needing to return the date by PersonID when the last time the Balance field went from a negative value to a positive value.

In the sample data below, for PersonID 1 it happened for 8th July 2019, for PersonID 2 it happened for 8th August 2019. There can be multiple times the value changes from negative to positive but it should only reference the latest time it happens.

[image]

This query from Gordon Linoff did the trick, but I need to also return the next_date as well.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by actiondate desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(balance) over (partition by personid order by actiondate) as next_balance
            from #temp t
           ) t
      where t.balance < 0 and
            t.next_balance > 0
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The extra column I'm needing that is not returning is "next_date", which may not necessarily be the day after:

[image]

Sample Data:

```
Create Table #temp
(
    PersonID int,
    ActionDate date,
    Balance money
)
insert into #temp
(
    PersonID,
    ActionDate,
    Balance
)
select
    1,
    '01 Jul 2019',
    -100
union all
select
    1,
    '02 Jul 2019',
    -45
union all
select
    1,
    '03 Jul 2019',
    -80
union all
select
    1,
    '04 Jul 2019',
    -20
union all
select
    1,
    '05 Jul 2019',
    40
union all
select
    1,
    '06 Jul 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    1,
    '07 Jul 2019',
    -90
union all
select
    1,
    '08 Jul 2019',
    -150
union all
select
    1,
    '09 Jul 2019',
    100
union all
select
    1,
    '10 Jul 2019',
    120
union all
select
    1,
    '11 Jul 2019',
    130
union all
select
    1,
    '12 Jul 2019',
    140
--
union all
select
    2,
    '01 Aug 2019',
    -100
union all
select
    2,
    '02 Aug 2019',
    -45
union all
select
    2,
    '03 Aug 2019',
    80
union all
select
    2,
    '04 Aug 2019',
    20
union all
select
    2,
    '05 Aug 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    2,
    '06 Aug 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    2,
    '07 Aug 2019',
    40
union all
select
    2,
    '08 Aug 2019',
    -40
union all
select
    2,
    '09 Aug 2019',
    45
union all
select
    2,
    '10 Aug 2019',
    65
union all
select
    2,
    '11 Aug 2019',
    23
union all
select
    2,
    '12 Aug 2019',
    105
union all
select
    3,
    '15 Aug 2019',
    -5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add next actiondate in a similar way as you have added next balance using lead function.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by actiondate desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(balance) over (partition by personid order by actiondate) as next_balance,
                   lead(actiondate) over (partition by personid order by actiondate) as next_actiondate
-------------------^ highlighted
            from #temp t
           ) t
      where t.balance < 0 and t.next_balance > 0
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I think you've got it right, but code-only answers with no explanation are usually discouraged on this site.  Also, please format the code into a code block and consider some style of indentation to make the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks @sridhar7, but as pwilcox said, can you please format it. The query as it stands gives syntax errors.